# How can I add CA certs as trusted for local user without root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, certificates

Is there a way for the CA certificate to be added on system wide, without root priviledges?

Answer (score 1):

Most programs on Debian and Ubuntu are compiled to use the system-wide certificate store, which is managed by the `ca-certificates` package and can be managed only by root.  Some individual programs, such as git and curl, provide individual ways to override the certificate store, but not all do.  There isn't any general way on a typical Debian or Ubuntu system to override trusted certificates as a user for all programs.

Comment: Well I found that `Fiddler` app was actually capturing my system traffic. while I wasn't running it as root.